# Double records in core-data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I got some code which saves data from a rss feed to a core-data database. It creates a object from the data. The code should check if the item is already in the database. But sometimes it does not seem to work. It sometimes fetches 1 item double. I am not sure where it is going wrong.

```
+(NieuwsItem *)NewNieuwsItemWithData:(NSMutableDictionary *)data withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

//Method for the creating of an new NieuwsItem object
NieuwsItem *item = nil;

//Create an fetch request to see if item allready is there
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

//Set the discriptions for the FetchRequest
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NieuwsItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", [data objectForKey:@"id"]];

//Catch the error
NSError *error = nil;

//Excecute the request
item = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

//If there are no errors and the item is not yet in the database
if (!error && !item ) {

    NSLog(@"Nieuw item aangemaakt met id");

    //Create new agenda item
    item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NieuwsItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Create an new date object 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *datum = [dateFormat dateFromString:[data objectForKey:@"pubDate"]];

    //And set the item data
    item.naam = [data objectForKey:@"title"];
    item.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[data objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
    item.text = [data objectForKey:@"description"];
    item.tumbURL = [data objectForKey:@"tumbafbeelding"];
    item.link = [data objectForKey:@"link"];
    item.datum = datum;

    //Clean
    [dateFormat release];


    //Save the item to the context 
    [context save:nil];

}

//Clean up 
[error release];


//Return the item
return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
...

//Catch the error
NSError *error = nil;

[request setFetchLimit:1]; //You shouldn't make a search for more than 1 element, so limit the fetch.

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                                         initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                                         managedObjectContext:context
                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
[fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (error) {
    // do something
    return nil;
}
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] > 0) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    item = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
//If there are no errors and the item is not yet in the database
if (!item) {
    ...
}
//Clean up 
[fetchedResultsController release];

//Return the item
return item;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the code but it doesn't quite work yet. When it updates the database it checks for the objects. The first query results always with 0 objects while they are in the database. It is just strange.

Comment: Would you mind to send your email again? Than I could send it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok got your mail you can remove it now :) I will send it after trying a few things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have added a extra save at the start of the method it is solved now. Core Data can be a strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the fetch request will return an error if no object with id is present. You might want to consider using the count of the object. Therefore substituting

`//Excecute the request
item = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];`

with

`NSInteger countForFetchRequest = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];`

If countForFetchRequest is equal zero then you can insert the object (the one with the given id) as a new object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the code but it doesn't work as it should yet. Every time it tries to update the database it checks for the objects. Always the first query results with 0 objects while they are in the database. It is just strange.

Comment: is that single = in `predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@"` a typo? I think that should be `id == %@`

Comment: it is indeed a single = but I still got the same weird bug.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have added a extra save at the start of the method it is solved now. Core Data can be a strange thing.